# Как в subject письма поставить имя пользователя?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

При смене данных пользователя в WooCommerce, высылается письмо администратору.
Как можно в поле темы "$subject" письма поставить фио пользователя? Вот часть кода:

```
function woocommerce_send_notification(){
    $body       = '';
    $to         = 'email@domain.com';   
    $subject    = 'Смена данных Имя Фамилия'; 

    $curr_user      = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id        = $curr_user->ID;
    $curr_username  = $curr_user->data->user_login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все данные о пользователе находятся в объекте `$curr_user`.

```
function woocommerce_send_notification() {
    $body = '';
    $to   = 'email@domain.com';

    $curr_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $subject   = 'Смена данных: ' . $curr_user->first_name . ' ' . $curr_user->last_name;

    $user_id       = $curr_user->ID;
    $curr_username = $curr_user->data->user_login;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Все работает.